# On what day(s) of Pessach which are not the weekly Shabbat are Shabbat rules to be observed?

Tags: shabbat, passover

During the Pessach week, some days are occasionally referred to as a Shabbat.
On which day or days are the 39 Melachot to be observed even if they don't fall on the weakly Shabbat?

Comment: "some days are occasionally referred to as a Shabbat" where?

Comment: That's the point, I found it in Christian literature. Just didn't want to mention it here;)

Comment: On none of them

Comment: Exodus 12:16 explicitly addresses this

Comment: ... finally, the answers confirm the Christian author but I wanted to double check in pure Judaism because the publication has a pronounced Christian apologetic character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H. Shevithath Yom Tov 1:1:

> ששת הימים האלו שאסרן הכתוב בעשיית מלאכה--שהן ראשון ושביעי של פסח,
> וראשון ושמיני של חג הסוכות, וביום חג השבועות, ובאחד לחודש השביעי--הן
> הנקראין ימים טובים.  ושביתת כולן שווה, שהן אסורין בכל מלאכת עבודה, חוץ
> ממלאכה שהיא לצורך אכילה, שנאמר "אך אשר ייאכל לכל נפש . . ." (שמות
> יב,טז).
>
> The six days on which the Torah forbade work are the first and seventh
> days of Pesah, the first and eighth days of the festival of Sukkoth,
> the festival of Shavuoth, and the first day of the seventh month. They
> are referred to as holidays. The [obligation to] rest is the same on
> all these days; it is forbidden to perform all types of servile labor
> (מלאכת עבודה), with the exception of those labors necessary for [the
> preparation of] food, as [implied by Exodus 12:16]: "Only that [labor]
> from which all souls will eat [may you perform]."

Answer (score 0):

Double AA answers:

Exodus 12:16 explicitly addresses this

> And in the first day there shall be an holy convocation, and in the seventh day there shall be an holy convocation to you; no manner of work shall be done in them, save that which every man must eat, that only may be done of you.

Comment: Note that on those days certain of the 39 melachot (those involved in food preparation) are permitted.